# Thrust Transform segmentation fault

Tags: cuda, segmentation-fault, thrust

I am trying to transform a device array to another device array as negations using transform function of thrust.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "device_functions.h"
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <vector> 
int main()
{  
    unsigned * dkeys = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dkeys, sizeof(unsigned) * size);    
    vector<unsigned> keys (size);
    std::iota(keys.begin(), keys.end(), 0);
    unsigned * key_raw = &keys[0];
    cudaMemcpy(dkeys, key_raw, sizeof(unsigned) * size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int *b = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &b, sizeof(int) * size);

    thrust::negate<int> op;
    thrust::transform(dkeys, dkeys + size, b, op);
    return 0;
 }
```

These lines throw Segmentation fault (core dumped). What could be the problem here?

Even

```
thrust::negate<int> op;
thrust::transform(dkeys, dkeys + size, dkeys, op);
```

also throws the same

Comment: Did you allocate the memory for `dkeys` ?

Comment: @pSoLT Yeah I did. Edited the post now

Comment: This would require a proper [MCVE] before someone could answer. Please edit one into your question

Comment: @talonmies yeah edited now

Comment: @Anbu: The code you have posted won't compile because `size` isn't defined anywhere

Comment: The problem is that `dkeys` is a device pointer, but thrust doesn't know that because you are passing it as a bare pointer instead of a thrust decorated device pointer or via container. According to the [thrust quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide), when bare pointers are passed to a thrust algorithm, thrust will dispatch the **host path**. The host path expects host pointers, and when it attempts to dereference the device pointers you have passed, you get a seg fault. There are several options to fix this; your question is a duplicate of several others.

Comment: @RobertCrovella yeah okay